# Can solana-keygen grind utilize a GPU?

Tags: wallet, solana-keygen

The help for `solana-keygen grind` says that the `--num-threads` option can be used to increase the number of threads. I imagine this is referring to CPU threads. Is there a way to make this work to use a GPU or a similar solution that uses a GPU to achieve faster results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `solana-keygen grind` is not making use of a GPU.

A Solana keypair is just an [Ed25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Ed25519) keypair, though.

There are few repos out there that can grind for Ed25519 keypairs using a GPU. You might want to try [this one here](https://github.com/mcf-rocks/solanity).

Comment: They have a warning, "It does not currently use a CSPRNG and any key generated by this tool is 100% not secure to use." Any thoughts on how practical that warning is? What makes it less safe than `solana-keygen grind`? I presume `solana-keygen` uses a CSPRNG?

Comment: The solanity repo says that it uses OS entropy to make it not deterministic. I suppose because that is not considered "perfect", they issue an academically proper warning that something slightly less than perfect non-determinism about OS entropy might allow someone to replay the exact grind and reproduce the keypair easier? It sounds like we're talking about an event that only happens once in a trillion universes and making it much more likely: an event that only happens once in a million universes. Is that what we're talking about here? If that's the case, I'm not going to worry. Thoughts?

Comment: The original repo chorus-one/solanity had that warning because it's deterministic. That's why mcf-rocks/solanity added some entropy, and my understanding is that it is now a CSPRNG. But they don't give any guarantees and neither do I, of course. I think you will need to do your own research here if your life depends on it.